# How do I check if users belongs to a certain model

Tags: django, django-models

I have models: Student, Teacher, and CustomUser.

A CustomUser belongs either to student or teacher.

When logged in, I want to check if the user is instance of student or teacher in the template html.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
{% if user is a student %}
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit_student_profile' %}">Profile</a>
{% elif user is a teacher %}
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit_teacher_profile' %}">Profile</a>
{% else %}
   <a>Error. Go signup as teacher or student!</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You need to show your models.

Answer (score 1):

simply create two variables (boolean)

**IsStudent, IsTeacher.**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
   is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)
```

i also, recommend following this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)

Good luck.